# Help identifying Sci-Fi channel movie about demons

Tags: story-identification

About 5 years ago I was watching a movie on The Sci-Fi Channel. It was about demons and there may have been a priest (shocking I know). The one scene I remember is this 20 something guy having a prostitute get in his car. She was possessed and he flips out when she begins manifesting (her face may have changed into a demon's face). He says Jesus and the demons get angry and defensive. He kicks her out of his car leaving her confused.

I tried to tape the show but the recorder didn't work and I always wondered how it ended

Comment: Isn't that the movie where a stable boy goes healing people and is really a reincarnation of Jesus (or as it turns out, not)?

Comment: I don't know the end.

Answer (score 4):

The description is pretty vague but if you saw it on SciFi then most likely you were watching [Saint Sinner](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0313016/).

Comment: I hate being that vague but that was all I remember after 5 years.

Comment: I hate to mark this as unanswered again I watched it and it was the wrong movie. I only said it was the right one after viewing the cover art.

Comment: @skids89: It's cool. It was good of you to mark it as correct while you thought it was, so that it didn't languish without an accepted answer if you had not returned.